# Determine various quarters ran based on start and end date in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to generate all the quarters between a date range using a formula. I have a start date and end date, based on this I would like to generate the various quarters in Google sheets

Example: Start Date: Jan 20 2022 & End Date: July 22 2022
Expected Q1, Q2, Q3

I can get the start and end quarters based on the dates but can anyone advise me how to get the in between quarters in google sheets?

The google sheets I have looks like below and I am trying to generate a flag (boolean) quarter column and later concatenate based on individual values to derive the collective quarters for a particular row

[image]

Comment: Can you show an example output of what you are looking for?

Comment: I am looking for the columns Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4 to be populated with 1 or 0 depending upon the start date and end date i.e., 1 if start & end date lies in Q1 else 0

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(ROW(A1:A10)&"×"&IFNA(VLOOKUP(
 IF(SEQUENCE(1, 1000, 0)<=DAYS(B1:B10, A1:A10), A1:A10+SEQUENCE(1, 1000, 0), ), 
 SPLIT(FLATTEN({"1/1/", "1/4/", "1/7/", "1/10/"}&
 SEQUENCE(4, 1, 2020)&"×"&{"Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4"}), "×"), 2, 1))), "×"), 
 "select max(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1"), "offset 1", 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: This formula does not work for me, it only populates in column1 and always remain as Q4

Comment: @shafeeqrahaman here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B9bkFUzhS2TKifrXS_1HFE6-7TDgDj5Oj_bHwqOiDng/edit#gid=1126092892